# SQL Query into Laravel Query Builder

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have this SQL Query and at the moment I don't know how to build this with the larval query builder

```
SELECT h1.Name, h2.Torvorlage from 
(SELECT Name, Player_ID FROM `Spieler` WHERE Vereins_ID = 1) h1 
left JOIN 
(SELECT Torvorlage, Player_ID FROM `SpielerStats` left join Spielplan on (SpielerStats.Spielplan_ID = Spielplan.Spielplan_ID) WHERE Spielplan.Spielplan_ID = 1 and Spielplan.Spieltag = 2) h2 
on h1.Player_ID = h2.Player_ID
```

Can anyone give me a example how to build this?

Comment: Add what you've attempted. It will help you in getting a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
DB::table('Spieler')->where('Vereins_ID','=',1)
       ->join('SpielerStats','SpielerStats.Player_ID','=','Spieler.Player_ID','left')
       ->select('SpielerStats.Torvorlage','Spieler.Name')
       ->join('Spielplan','SpielerStats.Spielplan_ID','=','Spielplan.Spielplan_ID','left')
       ->where('Spielplan.Spielplan_ID','=',1)
       ->where('Spielplan.Spieltag','=',2)->get();
```

Or

```
$d = DB::raw('(SELECT Torvorlage, Player_ID FROM `SpielerStats` left join Spielplan on (SpielerStats.Spielplan_ID = Spielplan.Spielplan_ID) WHERE Spielplan.Spielplan_ID = 1 and Spielplan.Spieltag = 2) as h2')


DB::table('Spieler')
    ->select('Spieler.Name','h2.Torvorlage')
    ->leftJoin($d, 'h2.Player_ID', '=', 'Spieler.Player_ID') 
    ->where('Vereins_ID','=',1)
    ->get();
```

Comment: the result is empty []

Comment: @Flamms please check I have added 1 more solution. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a better answer, you should explain what your query is doing. What is the relationship with these tables? In my experience, when I had a complicated SQL query to convert to Eloquent, I found that defining the relationships on the models solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with DB:Select

```
$spielerstats = DB::Select('SELECT h1.Name, h2.Torvorlage from 
(SELECT Name, Player_ID FROM `Spieler` WHERE Vereins_ID = 1) h1 
left JOIN 
(SELECT Torvorlage, Player_ID FROM `SpielerStats` left join Spielplan on (SpielerStats.Spielplan_ID = Spielplan.Spielplan_ID) WHERE Spielplan.Spielplan_ID = 1 and Spielplan.Spieltag = 1) h2 
on h1.Player_ID = h2.Player_ID');
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way but it works.